# extracting day, week, hour,date,year in pyspark from a string column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to extract day, week, hour,date,year in pyspark however after using `dayofweek` it shows `null` as output.

DF is something like this :

| Mailed Date |
| --- |
| Wed, 09/29/10 03:52 PM |
| Tue, 09/21/10 11:51 PM |
| Tue, 09/21/10 11:51 PM |
| Tue, 09/21/10 11:51 PM |

I am trying to have different column named `day` `day of week` `month` `year` and `hour of day`

however after using `from pyspark.sql.functions import year, month, dayofweek` it shows `null` as `day output column`

Code i have used:
`df01 = emaildf.withColumn('Day', dayofweek('Mailed_Date')).show(5)`

converted into timesetemp:
`df01 = vdf.withColumn("Mailed_Date",col("Mailed_Date").cast("Timestamp"))`

Output:[image]

Comment: you'd first have to convert the datetime to compatible timestamp format. see [`from_unixtime()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime) and [`unix_timestamp()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp.html#pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp) and [`to_timestamp()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp.html#pyspark-sql-functions-to-timestamp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, the string datetime provided is not in the default format, you'd have to convert the datetime to a readable format using `to_timestamp()`. Also, you'll need to set the timeParserPolicy to LEGACY, if you're parsing in spark 3.0+, due to the presence of week in the string.

```
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy', 'LEGACY')  # if spark 3.0+

ts_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('Wed, 09/29/10 03:52 PM',)]).toDF(['ts_str']). \
    withColumn('ts', func.to_timestamp('ts_str', 'EEE, MM/dd/yy hh:mm a')). \
    withColumn('year', func.year('ts')). \
    withColumn('month', func.month('ts')). \
    withColumn('dayofweek', func.dayofweek('ts')). \
    withColumn('hour', func.hour('ts')). \
    withColumn('minute', func.minute('ts'))

ts_sdf.show(truncate=False)

# +----------------------+-------------------+----+-----+---------+----+------+
# |ts_str                |ts                 |year|month|dayofweek|hour|minute|
# +----------------------+-------------------+----+-----+---------+----+------+
# |Wed, 09/29/10 03:52 PM|2010-09-29 15:52:00|2010|9    |4        |15  |52    |
# +----------------------+-------------------+----+-----+---------+----+------+

ts_sdf.printSchema()

# root
#  |-- ts_str: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- ts: timestamp (nullable = true)
#  |-- year: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- month: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- dayofweek: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- hour: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- minute: integer (nullable = true)
```